# How to drawing like handwring on canvas. and how to embed code in project

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am using this [**source code**](https://github.com/slightfoot/android-painter-example), but handwriting isn't smooth on large devices - it shows like *corners*.

[image]

I have library that works similarly to what I need, but I am unable to use [**this library**](https://github.com/ww6015132/SilkySignature) in my project (source code above).

Thanks in advance.